# Calculating decision tree depth from a column of data in R?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I'm trying to come up with a way to calculate the depth of a decision tree based on a few columns in a data frame in R.

For example, if I have some data that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  var = c("x1", NA, "x2", "x9", NA, NA, NA, 'x5', NA, "x3", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA),
  treeNumber = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)
) 

> df
# A tibble: 15 × 2
   var   treeNumber
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 x1             1
 2 NA             1
 3 x2             1
 4 x9             1
 5 NA             1
 6 NA             1
 7 NA             1
 8 x5             2
 9 NA             2
10 x3             2
11 NA             2
12 NA             2
13 x1             3
14 NA             3
15 NA             3
```

And if the above data creates 3 decision trees that look like:

[image: 3 trees]

As we can see, the terminal nodes are are given as `NA` in `df` (I have omitted the actual decision/spit values [seen in the picture] column from the data frame for simplicity).

For clarity, we can see that `treeNumber 1` has a depth of 2 (if we index the root node at 0). `treeNumber 2` has a depth of 1 and `treeNumber 3` has a depth of 0.

The rule or direction that the trees are being drawn from the data frame is in a left-to-right type fashion. For example, if we just look at tree number 2, we can see how the shape of the data frame corresponds to how the tree is drawn:

[image: single tree]

Again, for clarity, if we just look at `treeNumber` = 2 in the data frame, we can see in the `var` column it says `x5, NA, x3, NA, NA`. This corresponds to how the image is drawn from left-to-right.

Im trying to figure out a way to calculate each of the tree's depths.

One solution is to use `igraph` or similar and turn each tree into a graph object and then use the function `igraph::bfs()` to calculate the depth. However, if I have many trees (e.g, 100,000) iterating through them all and turning them into graph objects is very time consuming. I was hoping to find a way to calculate the depth from just using the data provided in my example.

Any suggestions as to how I could achieve this?

**EDIT**

As per some of the suggestions, I will provide a small example of the complexity of trying to calculate the tree depth and why Im finding it difficult to achieve.

For example, if my data looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(
  var = c("x1", "x2", NA, NA, "x9", NA, NA, "x1", NA, "x2", "x3", NA, NA, NA),
  treeNumber = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
)
```

Here, I only have 2 trees. If I were to plot the trees, they would look like this:

[image: tree example]

So, here we can see that `treeNumber 1` has a depth of 1 but `treeNumber 2` has a depth of 2. Each tree has the same number terminal nodes (i.e., `NAs`) and each tree has the same number of non-terminal nodes... but the depth of each tree differs. This, unfortunatley, means that we can't just filter out the `NA`s and summarise the number of rows.

Comment: If your setup is as described, you don't need anything special. This uses `dplyr`: `df %>% group_by(treeNumber) %>% summarise(n())`.

Comment: Im afraid it doesn't work that way. I'm not looking to summarise the count of rows. Im trying to find the depth of the trees. For example, `treeNumber 1` has 7 rows (where each row corresponds to a node in the tree), but as you can see in the image, it only has a depth of 2 (if we say the root node is at a depth of 0).

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood what you wanted. Wow, I was way off. I swear I read your post! Anyway, this should work: `filter(df, !is.na(var)) %>% group_by(treeNumber) %>% summarise(count = n()-1)`.

Comment: Could you try:
`df %>% group_by(treeNumber) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(!is.na(.))-1))` - this returns `var` values of 2,1, and 0 for `treeNumber` 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

Comment: These suggestions are great. But, unfortunately, they only work in for the example I have given. If the tree structure is more complex, these methods don't work. I will edit my question with a small example of where these methods fail.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works, regardless of the tree shape or size. See if you can find fault in it.

```
# empty data frame to store results 
  # assuming there will be many trees
treeDepth = data.frame(tree = numeric(), depth = numeric())

# loop through each tree number
for(i in unique(df$treeNumber)){
  df2 <- df %>% 
    filter(treeNumber == i) %>%           # filter for the tree number
    mutate(TF = ifelse(is.na(var) == F,   # determine with are are NA or not
                       TRUE, FALSE))
  s <- rle(df2$TF)                        # count consecutive strings of T or F
  
  # frame and filter the consecutive counts data
  s2 <- data.frame(runs = s$lengths %>% unlist(), 
                   TF = s$values %>% unlist()) %>% 
    filter(TF == T)
  
  # if the only T is the first, it's a 0
  if(nrow(s2) == 1){
    depth = 0
  } else{       # otherwise ignore the first T, look for the longest string of Ts
    depth = max(s2[2:nrow(s2), ]$runs) # don't include first T
  }
  # add the tree number & depth to df before next loop
  treeDepth[nrow(treeDepth) + 1, ] <- c(i, depth)
}

treeDepth 
#   tree depth
# 1    1     2
# 2    2     1
# 3    3     0
# 4    4     1
# 5    5     2
```